# How to determine if a Dart list is a fixed list?

Tags: dart

How can I determine, at runtime, if a list in Dart is a "fixed list" ?

There are (at least) three ways to create a fixed-length list in Dart:

```
var fixed = new List(5); // fixed at five elements
var alsoFixed = new List.filled(5, null); // fixed at five elements, set to null
var fixedToo = new List.from([1,2,3], growable: false);
```

How do I ask, in code, if `fixed`, `alsoFixed`, and `fixedToo` are fixed-length?

Answer (score 6):

You can try to add an element and remove it to know if the list has a fixed length:

```dart
bool hasFixLength(List list) {
  try {
    list
      ..add(null)
      ..removeLast();
    return false;
  } on UnsupportedError {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why both adding and removing?

Comment: To keep the list unchanged in the case of mutable lists.

Answer (score 0):

`runtimeType` can be used for that, but shouldn't because it's not very reliable especially with dart2js otherwise there isn't. AFAIR there were several requests to add support for this but was declined.

Comment: What would I check with runtimeType ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm just on my phone. You should get some weird internal type names which are different for dynamic and fixed length lists.

Comment: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/built_collection might help, depending on the use case. It provides unmodiable collections and builders which can be passed around separately (a Google project)

Answer (score 0):

We did not add any way to see if a list is fixed (or `const`).

So far, we have only encountered one use case where this would fit into well-written code: checking that a function returned a mutable array. We decided that this use case was not worth changing the API.

Most of the time, an additional boolean flag that asks to modify an existing list is cleaner (since then, the caller can decide what the callee should do).

If you have another use case, please let us know and we will investigate.