# Can you specify a List<T> with specific length as a type

Tags: dart

Let's assume we are designing a sudoku model which takes 9 Tile3x3 objects as a list. How would I explicitly specify the length of List so that it can only have 9 objects of Tile3x3s.

```dart
class Sudoku {
  List<Tile3x3> tiles3x3;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a fixed length list in Dart like so:

```
class Sudoku {
  final var tiles3x3 = List<Tile3x3>(9);
}
```

`tiles3x3` will not support adding or changing the length of the List.

Comment: Thanks I've tried that but how about a class with a parameter which constructs the Sudoku with the given tiles 3x3? For example:`class Sudoku {
  final List<Tile3x3> tiles3x3;
  Sudoku(this.tiles3x3);
}` The above example already declares the value and has the type as var.

Comment: You could test in the constructor if the list a fixed length list or not (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/31255761/5720160 for an example of how to do that). But otherwise, Dart doesn't differentiate between fixed length and dynamic length Lists by type.

Comment: You could also test in the constructor if the list size is the right size, and make a copy of that list for the class, so then the data won't be modified outside.